# Where to start for multi-variable optimization problem with ML?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm looking for a place to start for solving an optimization problem with ML.

Let's say I have a huge pile of bricks, and I need to pick out 50 bricks from this pile to arrange to make a wall. My bricks are all different types: some of my bricks are stronger than others and some are heavier, so each time I select a set of bricks, I need to do a (relatively slow) structural calculation to make sure the wall won't fall down. I have too many bricks in my pile in order to try every permutation by brute force, so I would like to use ML to help me find arrangements of bricks that are likely to work, because I have a few hundred previous sets that I know are ok.

There are also some subjective criteria that the wall needs to meet--maybe it looks ugly if I have too many green bricks. I have a good idea which criteria are looked at subjectively (e.g., I know the architect cares how many green bricks there are), but I would like to train an ML model with previous data to know what kind of weights to give these criteria, because I don't have any hard limit on how many green bricks are too many--I just have a dataset that shows that the architect didn't like some walls in the past that had a lot of green bricks.

Is this a problem that ML can help me solve? What frameworks/models should I investigate to solve this kind of problem? I'm having a hard time zeroing in on a place to start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends a bit on whether you need help coming up with (generating) novel combinations, or whether you want to understand the variables that affect the likelihood of success/acceptance.

If the later, you could approach this as a classification task. From your description you might come up with some features that describe the set of bricks you tested/will test such as: number of green bricks, total weight of bricks, average weight of bricks, weight of bottom row of bricks.

You'd then have a table where each row would be a configuration of bricks and each column would be a feature generated above. You have and additional column for your target which would be true/false depending if the configuration was successful.

```
+---------+------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
| n_green | weight_sum | weight_mean | weight_br_sum | target_success |
+---------+------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
|      10 |        102 |         0.6 |            15 | true           |
|       2 |         60 |         0.5 |            30 | false          |
|      40 |        250 |         1.1 |            15 | true           |
+---------+------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
```

You could use a linear model (e.g. [Logistic Regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)) with X the array of values from columns n_green:target_success and y being the target column. You can then look at the coefficients of the fitted model to understand what features have the largest effect on success (although you should [scale your features first](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html)).

You can then generate new combinations and run them through the fitted model to get a probability of success.

If the arrangement/configuration of bricks is important you might want to investigate Neural networks and specifically Convolutional Neural Networks ([CNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network)). You would have to use a library like [ELI5](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [Shap](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) to investigate feature importance.

If the former you should investigate [GANs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network).